# Is there a way to display an icon in the Icon Tray only while my "systemctl start app.service" is running?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I cannot find any example how can I implement such particular needs with a personalized Manage Systemd Services in Linux. I need to create in Ubuntu/Linux one function where display an Icon in the System Tray Icon (on Desktop Dash Board Tray small Icon) only if my service `systemctl` it's running in background , if not will not display anything, this it will helps me to understand if in every reboot of the system, the service will run automatically fine (as it makes now).

My System Service file it's located as normal in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/app.service`, and if I will right click on this personalized Icon, i need to have one small pop-up that says `Kill the App Service` or `Close the App Service` or just `Exit` (this command will be run this background function `sudo systemctl stop app.service`).

I'm not an expert in coding, but I just started, can someone please help me on that how to write this code?

Thanks a lot

**Edit 2-2:**

@Deepak, like this it seems correct :

```
while (True):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon('/home/USER/.app_example/app.png'), parent=app)
menu = QMenu()
exitAction = menu.addAction('Exit')

result = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'systemctl', 'status', 'app_example.service'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')

if "active (running)" in result:
    trayIcon.setToolTip('App Example')
    trayIcon.show()
    pass
else:
    sys.exit()
time.sleep(5)
exitAction.triggered.connect(app.quit)
trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do polling via python. Check every 5 seconds if the keyword "active (running)" is in the output of "sudo systemctl status app.service".

The code below should be added to the code for the tray icon. It will kill the tray icon when the service is not running.

```
import subprocess
import time
while (True):
    result = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'systemctl', 'status', 'app.service'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
    if "active (running)" in result:
        pass
    else:
        sys.exit()
    time.sleep(5)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I made well the coding in Python in this way above on Edit 2, something it's working but not sure on that. It's that correct?

Comment: @Niewbie Try remove the "sys.exit(app.exec_())" line you added before the while loop. (Don't remove the one inside the while loop, remove the one before it.) That line doesn't make sense to me. The code will not reach the while loop because that line causes it to exit before reaching the while loop.

Comment: wait  a moment because I'm really Newbie, because I think also in this way the icon will show anyway (and it's incorrect), and I need to move the coding of the icon in  your only if will be active.....I know it's annoyng to support the people like me , but please be gentle because I'm really new on such world... Let me make few test and I will go back to you...

Comment: @Niewbie take your time. It's not annoying at all. I'm happy to help 

Comment: @Joshua thank you very much for your understanding, I have correct the draft coding and now it's WORKING thank you so much guys!!!!

Comment: @Joshua I didn't include the import/Headers in the coding, because I cannot understand why (Rob) pointy me out it. Anyway it seems that the 2 Exit functions are coexisting in this way, and it's the unique way to let it work. It's that correct the above "Exit" toghether? I hope it's usefull for somebody else this